# EF Core 7 - Adding a new object but the ID value has a temporary value

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

Upgrading from EF 6 to EF Core 7 and I can't figure this out. On our client we assign new id values to objects which are lower then zero.  When we map the objects up to EF6, it realises its a new object because we called `Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Added;` on the parent and all the children are added. When it comes to inserting it in the database, objects are assigned a new value via SQL Server and all references on all objects are updated as well.

For example

```
namespace EFCorePlayground
{
    public class AtCalc
    {
        public long Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}

namespace EFCorePlayground.Config
{
    public class AtCalcConfig : IEntityTypeConfiguration<AtCalc>
    {
        public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<AtCalc> builder)
        {
            // table
            builder.ToTable("AtCalc");

            // key
            builder.Property(e => e.Id).ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
            builder.HasKey(e => e.Id);

            builder.OwnsOne(e => e.Details);
        }
    }
}
```

On the server if i created a new object like so i get an error, now its trying to save the MyObject with an ID of -1, why?

```
using EFCorePlayground;
using EFCorePlayground.Config;

var context = new DataContext();
var m = new AtCalc { Id = -1, Name = "bob" };

context.Add(m).State = Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityState.Added;
context.SaveChanges();

Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");
```

I get this error:

> Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'AtCalc' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF

How can I get EF Core to work like EF6 and give it a new `Id` value? I also get this problem when working with child objects as well, but I am guessing there is a solution I am missing.

According to [this](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/efcore/working-with-disconnected-entity-graph-ef-core.aspx) page, this should work? Can someone point me in the right direction?

EDIT: I do not want it to insert -1, I just give it a unique value on the client, so that if I have to reference the value somewhere else when doing this save, it would know which object to use.  As someone has said in the comments below, EF6 ignores any value that is set on an ID column and overwrites it with the value from the database, is there a way to configure this functionality?

Comment: Set it to 0 (or just do not set it at all because it is default value for `int`). Why `-1`?

Comment: The error you are getting is not specific to Entity Framework. When column is configured as an Identity and you try to insert an explicit value to that column this error will raise. Instead of configuring `ValueGeneratedOnAdd` you can configure your column to use a sequence. Using a sequence will give you identity-like incrementing ids and also allows you to insert specific ids.

Comment: It is worth noting that in EF6 (not Core) EF would ignore values set in Identity Columns. Setting it to -1, 0, or 101 explicitly would have no effect. On insert it would simply be excluded from the INSERT statement generation. EF Core looks to operate a bit differently and when it sees an explicit non-zero value for a column it includes it in the INSERT statement resulting in the database rejecting it. Honestly IMO this is the better scenario to avoid the silent insert of duplicate data when someone inserts rows with detached references to existing data, duplicating those references.

Comment: @StevePy this is my point exactly, I want EFCore to ignore any value I have stated and overwrite it with the database generated value

Comment: Then with EF Core you need to leave the value as the type default. (0 for int). If this is an existing code base where there is code setting values to -1 and potentially checking for -1 this means you essentially need to search and replace these to use 0.

Comment: @StevePy I did that yesterday after all the mapping from dto to entity was done but for some reason it tried to save 0 as the id as well. I will try this again today to be sure and upload the code to replicate

Comment: Turn off `builder.Property(e => e.Id).ValueGeneratedOnAdd();` If you want to be explicit about the identity use `builder.Property(e => e.Id).DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);`

Answer (score 1):

Because you specified that the Id will increase by itself(            builder.Property(e => e.Id).ValueGeneratedOnAdd();), but you have to set it manually, which is not possible

Unless you disable it altogether

```
  builder.Property(e => e.Id).ValueGeneratedNever();
```

Or disable it temporarily like the code below

You must set off,on "SET IDENTITY_INSERT "

```
 using (var transaction = context.Database.BeginTransaction())
        {
            AtCalc m = new AtCalc { Id = -1, Name = "bob" };

            context.Database.ExecuteSqlInterpolated($"SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.AtCalc ON;");
            context.Add(m).State = Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityState.Added;
            context.SaveChanges();
            context.Database.ExecuteSqlInterpolated($"SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.AtCalc OFF");
            transaction.Commit();
        }
```